# path to google cloud bucket when running programs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

When I download files to the bucket I use the command: `gsutil -u absolute-bison-xxxxx cp $FILE gs://bucket_1` which works fine.

I am running downstream programs that I want the output to be saved to the same bucket, but when I for instance type: `-output gs://bucket_1/file.out` to specify the folder for the output, it does not recognise the bucket as a place to store the output. How do I set the path to the bucket?

Comment: I think we normally say we "upload" files to a bucket.  I hear you say that you want applications to have their output saved to an object in a bucket and that you supply a command line argument of `-output gs://bucket_1/file.out`.  What is the nature of that application?  Is it able to handle writes to Google Cloud Storage?  Remember ...  GCS is not an extension to the local file system.  If the app thinks it is writing to the local file system it won't see GCS.  If you need that, look into "gcsfuse"

Answer (score 0):

From the command you have posted on your question, I think you are using Cloud SDK as stated in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#description) to copy files from your computer to your bucket.

If that is the case, following Kolban’s comment, you could use [Cloud Storage FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) to mount your Google Cloud Storage bucket as a file system.

In order to use Cloud Storage Fuse, you should be running an OS based on Linux kernel version 3.10 or newer, or Mac OS X 10.10.2 as stated on the  [installation notes](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/installing.md); also, you could run it from Google Compute Engine VMs.

You could begin installing it following the [installation notes](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/installing.md) and following this [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PCqL38coas8).

> For more information about using Cloud Storage FUSE, or to file an issue, go to the Google Cloud [GitHub repository].
> For a fully-supported file system product in Google Cloud, see [Filestore](https://cloud.google.com/filestore).

You could use Firestore as recommended in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse). To be used locally on your machine, you could follow [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/remote-mounting).